# How to send the data from a CGImageRef to an Magick++ blob?

Tags: c++, magick++

I'm trying to take a screenshot with `CGDisplayCreateImage` and then send them to Magick++ to do some basic image manipulation. Right now I'm saving the images to files, but I want to be able to store them in a Magick++ blob.

I've already seen this question: [How to convert from CGImageRef to GraphicsMagick Blob type?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17480284/how-to-convert-from-cgimageref-to-graphicsmagick-blob-type), but I'm using C++ and I can't find an alternative to `NSData`.

Answer (score 0):

You should be able to manage without `NSData` by using `std::vector<unsigned char> MyCopiedData`. Then it would be just a simple procedure of `Magick::Blob(MyCopiedData.data(),MyCopiedData.size())`.

But then `NSData` & `CFDataRef` are interchangeable, and considered "[Toll-Free Bridge](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/General/Conceptual/CocoaEncyclopedia/Toll-FreeBridgin/Toll-FreeBridgin.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40010810-CH2)". It wouldn't take much effort to include Foundation libraries & leverage the benefits of `NSData` class.